# Is it possible to use CV2 to remove internal contours in this binary mask?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I'm working on a network that outputs binary masks for corneal endothelial cells. At first, the masks look like this:

[image: Original mask]

I only want to retain the whole cells of the mask (complete enclosed edges, want to remove all stray edges). After some post-processing w/ CV2 and scikit, I've come to the following image (Partially cleaned mask):

[image: Partially cleaned mask].

As you can see, all the stray "external" edges have been removed, which I accomplished w/ cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL. However, there are still stray internal edges in the image that I can't seem to get rid of. I'm still a bit new to CV2 and scikit, so I'm not exactly sure what to try.

I've outlined a few examples of the edges I'd like to remove.

[image: Edges I'd like to remove]

Here is the code I'm currently using to clean up the stray external images post-skeletonization.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load the binary mask image
mask = cv2.imread('pruned_result.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Find contours in the opened image
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Create a mask for valid cells
filtered_mask = np.zeros_like(mask)
cv2.drawContours(filtered_mask, contours, -1, 255, thickness=cv2.FILLED)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))

# Perform morphological opening to remove small stray edges
opened = cv2.morphologyEx(filtered_mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

# Perform morphological closing to fill in any holes
closed = cv2.morphologyEx(opened, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

cutout_image = cv2.bitwise_and(mask, closed)

# Save the resulting image with stray edges removed
cv2.imwrite('filtered_mask.png', cutout_image)
```

Comment: please confirm if you want to remove **all edges** that are not closed.

Comment: yes! all edges that are not closed. thank you.

Comment: The skeletonization operation usually has an option on whether to remove the endpoints or not. Removing the endpoints will produce the result you’re looking for. For example in DIPlib you’d do [`dip.EuclideanSkeleton(binary_image, "loose ends away")`](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/binary.html#dip-EuclideanSkeleton-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-L-dip-String-CL-dip-String-CL).

Comment: I was able to get it running, and am passing in a binary image. Running into an error that the Image is not binary. Is there anything wrong with my code? `import cv2
import diplib as dip
import numpy as np

# Load image as grayscale
image = cv2.imread('filtered_mask.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Threshold to get binary mask
_, mask = cv2.threshold(image, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

mask = dip.EuclideanSkeleton(mask, "loose ends away")

# Save the result
cv2.imwrite('test.png', mask)
`